# How to set a default time on p-calendar

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, p-calendar

I have the following `p-calendar` on my page:

```
    <p-calendar [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}"
            dateFormat="dd-mm-yy" [formControl]="start" [showTime]="true"
            [showSeconds]="false" hourFormat="24" inputId="time">
    </p-calendar>
```

My typescript declaration for `start`:

```
  start = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
```

At present when I load my page, the default time is the time of me opening my page, I need to set the default time to 8:00am regarding of time of day, whilst leaving the calendar field as null, I've tried setting a default date but I can't set the time only, the date field keeps getting populated too, does anyone know how to set a default time?

Comment: Could you separate date setting from time setting ?  
- hide time time in `<p-calendar [showTime] ="false" .... > </p-calendar>.
- add new `<p-calendar-timeonly> </p-calendar-timeonly>`
- create a new `formControl` for `startTime`

Answer (score 1):

In Primeng calendar, there is a property called `defaultDate`.
Just set this property like this:

```
<p-calendar [defaultDate]="defaultTime" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
    [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" dateFormat="dd-mm-yy"
    [formControl]="start" [showTime]="true" [showSeconds]="false"
    hourFormat="24" inputId="time">
</p-calendar>
```

In your ts file, define defaultTime variable like this:

```
defaultTime: Date;

ngOnInit() {
  this.defaultTime = new Date();
  defaultTime.setHours(8, 0, 0);
}
```